# Second y axis displaced

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-axes

I am quite new to gnuplot. And I've got problem with secondary y axis. When I try to plot two curves into one graph with two different y axis, the second one is moved down a little bit. I mean that if you draw a straight line parallel to the x axis at y1 = 0, you get different y2 values. I want both y axes to start at the same point y1=0 ~ y2=0.

Here is the picture better describing my problem:

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: even though you said "two different y axis", you want both the left and the right y axis to be exactly the same, starting and ending at exactly the same values and covering the exact same range?

Comment: No, just starting at the same value.

Comment: If those axes are correlated (e.g. y1 = 10*y2) then you could use `set link` (requires version 5). Otherwise you must do that manually by selecting the ranges.